# How to execute a Shell method in a Controller?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using a cakephp3 plugin to manage a mail queue to send newsletter (Lorenzo Cakephp Email Queue). It works fine, but I need to use a Shell method with the bake command to send the newsletter. 
It is not a problem with a cron job, but I would like to be able to send test mail without waiting for the cron job. 
I tried to call the bake command with a php exec command, but it does not work (maybe a right problem ?) but I don't have access to the server to manage the rights. But, as the method and the controller are both in cakephp, I think it's weird to do it with a console (external) bake call...

Is there a way to call a Shell method from a Controller, which would be the "cleanest" and easiest way ?

Thanks all for you help !

Answer (score 0):

> which would be the "cleanest" and easiest way ?

A shell should be considered similar to a controller - controllers don't call controllers.

Consider putting [the cli logic](https://github.com/lorenzo/cakephp-email-queue/blob/master/src/Shell/SenderShell.php#L54-L112) in a common place and have the cli and controller action call that, not each other. The relevant cli code is a few lines of code, but it's not actually doing anything complex, just looping on the emails to be sent, and sending them one by one.

> I need to use a Shell method with the bake command to send the newsletter

Note that `bake` is *a* cli, it is not "the" cli, and forms no part of the [runtime usage of that plugin](https://github.com/lorenzo/cakephp-email-queue#sending-emails).

```
bin/cake EmailQueue.sender -h
```

It may not work currently, because you're using the wrong cli commands to try and run it from your controller action - though it's not a very good idea/design to do it that way anyway.

Comment: Thanks AD7six. Indeed, I talked about "bake", but I meant "cake". Finally, I succeeded using the php 'exec' command to launch the EmailQueue.sender :  exec("/bin/bash ".Configure::read('App.paths.websiteRootPath')."/cms/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender", $result);

Comment: `though it's not a very good idea/design to do it that way anyway`

Comment: This is the way the plugin is made... And I took a plugin in order not to develop it myselft